# How do you remove all spaces in an Excel character string?

Tags: excel, replace, find, substitution

I am trying to remove all spaces in a string.

"Find and Replace" returns no replacements and "Substitute returns the exact same value in the cell.

=SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "")

where A1 is some string like "Mark McGwire"

I expect the substitute function to return "MarkMcGwire", but it just returns "Mark McGwire".

Comment: Can you copy the space in its own cell and get its `CODE()`? If it's not 32, you don't have an actual space there but something else

Comment: What else could it be, and how would I go about converting it to a space if that is possible?

Comment: What does `=CODE(MID(A1,5,1))` return?

Comment: That code returns 160

Comment: So use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(160),"")`.